# Vertical Scroll in Desktop Change to Carousel in Mobile View

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is the example of the view. Sorry i just made a structure in the paint.
[image]

And I want it to be carousel view in mobile.

What are the options to do that?
Except in cloning.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with CSS Media Queries

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
```

In other words, you can apply different CSS styles on the very same elements depending on your screen size.

You can have a loo at using Bootstrap, Foundation.